# Program only works in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, kernel32

I recently created a C# application that monitors a program's memory. It's fully functioning in visual studio, but when I try to run the executable file found in the debug folder, it doesn't work properly. The program utilizes the Kernel32.dll library. I already tried running the program with administrator rights, but it still doesn't work. Also creating a copy of the Kernel32.dll and placing it in the debug folder didn't help.

Here is the foundation to my code if it helps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Memory_Seeker_CMD
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Kernel kernel = new Kernel();

            Dictionary<string, int> memoryList = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            memoryList = kernel.SearchMemoryByInt("Memory Tester", 25);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> memory in memoryList)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", memory.Key, memory.Value);

            Console.ReadKey();
            memoryList = kernel.SearchMemoryByInt("Memory Tester", 5, memoryList);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> memory in memoryList)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", memory.Key, memory.Value);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Kernel
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess, int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern void GetSystemInfo(out SYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int VirtualQueryEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, out MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer, uint dwLength);

        const int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400;
        const int MEM_COMMIT = 0x00001000;
        const int PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04;
        const int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;

        public struct MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION
        {
            public int BaseAddress;
            public int AllocationBase;
            public int AllocationProtect;
            public int RegionSize;
            public int State;
            public int Protect;
            public int lType;
        }

        public struct SYSTEM_INFO
        {
            public ushort processorArchitecture;
            ushort reserved;
            public uint pageSize;
            public IntPtr minimumApplicationAddress;
            public IntPtr maximumApplicationAddress;
            public IntPtr activeProcessorMask;
            public uint numberOfProcessors;
            public uint processorType;
            public uint allocationGranularity;
            public ushort processorLevel;
            public ushort processorRevision;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, int> SearchMemoryByInt(string processName, int value)
        {
            //this function searches through a program's memory to find a value
        }

        public Dictionary<string, int> SearchMemoryByInt(string processName, int value, Dictionary<string, int> memoryList)
        {
            //this function searches through a program's memory to find a value
        }

        public Dictionary<string, int> SearchAllMemory(string processName)
        {
            //this function searches through a program's memory and returns all results
        }
    }
}
```

Don't mind the file directory for the program because I already tried placing the executable in my local drive.

[image: Running with Visual Studio]

[image: Running without Visual Studio]

Comment: What happens? What doesn't work?

Comment: When I don't run the program in visual studio, it seems like the program can't access the kernel32 library because when I try to search a program's memory, nothing is returned. When I run the program in visual studio, the program is able to return the proper value when searching though a program's memory. I'll add pictures for a better explanation.

Comment: @DesertPigeon what if you right click - run as admin?

Comment: I already tried that and admin rights didn't do anything

Comment: Sounds like there it has something to do with the environment variables. Try opening the command window with "Tools">"Visual studio command prompt" and then start your program from that command window.

Comment: If it couldn't access `kernel32`, it wouldn't load at all, as that's part of the Windows system core. You've invented a problem based on zero information to indicate that's the problem. What does the Event Log tell you? What happens if you put in some logging code that traces your code execution? What happens if you actually try to troubleshoot the problem instead of just wildly speculating about the cause? The code you've posted for your `kernel` class does absolutely nothing (they're empty methods) - they don't do anything. Why would you expect other behavior than what you're seeing?

Comment: in order to help you you must add the implementation of SearchMemoryByInt